# Java - Overloaded method takes interfaces for arguments. Which method is called and why?

Tags: java, ambiguous

I have an object which implements two interfaces (specifically the `Serializable` and `java.security.Key` interfaces). This object's class also has two static methods: one that takes a `Serializable` object and one that takes a `Key` object. Here is some example code:

```
public class Subclass implements Serializable, java.security.Key{
   public static void test(Serializable s) {
      System.out.println("Ser");
   }
   public static void test(java.security.Key k) {
      System.out.println("Key");
   }

   public static void main(String[]args){
      test(new Subclass());
   }

}
```

Now when I run the above main method, no error is thrown and Java calls the `test(Key)` method. BUT, when I change the `Serializable` interface to something else (I change the parameter in the `test(Serializable)` and change the super interface of `Subclass`) to something else, my IDE shows me an error:

> The method `test(Key)` is ambiguous for the type `SubClass`.

What I want to know is, why does Java allow this kind of method ambiguity with the `Serializable` interface and no others?

Comment: What were the other types you used? These *something else*'s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Reason this works and the `test(java.security.Key k)` is called is because `java.security.Key` extends `Serializable` itself, hence `java.security.Key` is *more specialized* than `Serializable` and is preferred on method invocation.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5